# How to approach solving for $x$? $(1+x)^2 = 1.21$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, square-numbers

I'm trying to solve for $x$ in the following equation, but don't know how to solve it without using a graphing calculator.

$$(1+x)^2 = 1.21$$

Is there a rule I'm supposed to follow?

Comment: Hint: $1.21 = \frac{121}{100}$

Answer (score 6):

You can solve this as a general quadratic equation, but the special form makes it easier. In general (for $a \ge 0$):
$$x^2 = a \Leftrightarrow x = \pm \sqrt{a}$$

In your case, since $1.1^2 = 1.21$, proceed as follows:
$$\left(1+x\right)^2 = 1.21 \Leftrightarrow 1+x = \pm 1.1 \Leftrightarrow x = \ldots$$

Comment: Oh! So I just need find the square root of both sides of the equation. Thanks @stacktd !

Comment: More or less: be careful that a positive number $a$ has two square roots, the positive one is written as $\sqrt{a}$. If you decide to literally "take the square root of both sides", note that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice, you can also follow this method $$(1+x)^2=1.21$$
$$(1+x)^2=(1.1)^2$$
$$|1+x|=1.1$$
$$1+x=\pm1.1$$
$$x=-1\pm1.1$$
$$x=\color{red}{0.1},\ \color{red}{-2.1} $$

Answer (score 1):

Notice:

- $$x^2=y\Longleftrightarrow x=\pm\sqrt{y}$$
- $$y+x=z\Longleftrightarrow y=z-x$$

So:

$$(a+b)^2=c\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$a+b=\pm\sqrt{c}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$a=\pm\sqrt{c}-b$$

With your problem we get:

$$(1+x)^2=1.21\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$1+x=\pm\sqrt{1.21}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{1.21}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Here,

$$(1+x)^2=1.21$$
$$(1+x)=\pm 1.1$$

Taking $+$ve,
$x=0.1$

Taking $-$ve,
$x=-2.1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you learnt that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$, observe that

$$(1+x)^2=1+2x+x^2=1.21=1+2\cdot0.1+0.01^2$$ and conclude.